# Why is there no git showtool?

Tags: git, git-bash

The command `git diff` was extensively used by me when working with git. It allow me to see the changes between different versions.

In the past I use it also to see the changes introduced by one specific commit, by mean of `git diff <ref>~1..<ref>`. That was until I did discover the `git show <ref>` that performs exactly that way.

After that I did discover the `git difftool` command that use to provide the same feature than `git diff` but triggering a visual diff comparison.

Why doesn't exist a command `git showtool`? It would be very usefull to verify visually the change introduced by a commit, and I guess that is needed a lot.

Do you have one alternative for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the command is not available. I use this alias:

```
[alias]
    showtool = "!showci () { rev=${1:-HEAD}; git difftool $rev~1 $rev; }; showci $1"
```